# What is the method prototype in a dalvik file?

Tags: dalvik

Can someone explain me what the method prototype in the dalvik file does? According to Google this terminology is only C relevant and not Java, so the Question is what does it inside the dalvik?`

So is the prototype alike the method signature? Because it contains the following items: The Short Form String descriptor, the return type and the parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method_id_item contains a reference to a proto_id_item, which defines the arguments and return type for that method. So yes, it is the method signature.